# Meta + Comma - откуда взялось и что это за клавиши

Tags: phpstorm

Как такое может быть - вчера settings открывался сочетанием Ctrl+Alt+S - сегодня это уже не работает - в File предлагается теперь открывать сочетанием Meta+Comma - что я или ОНО наделало, что за клавиши такие - Meta и Comma(у меня Desktop, Windows-10) - ??
Или с такими глюками пора к лекарю?
Спасибо!

Comment: Meta (иногда super) - это клавиша с меняющимися от ОС к ОС функциями, которая в классической клавиатуре помечается символом Windows и применительно к Windows зовется просто win. Вы скорее всего сменили раскладку по умолчанию в тех же настройках с windows на что-то другое.

Comment: проверьте настройки - похоже, в File | Settings | Keymap выбран какой-то keymap для OSX. Попробуйте выбрать **Default**

Comment: Вы правы - спасибо - вернул необх. пресет клавиш !!))